# Why do CheckedListBox's SelectedItem work differently depending on how the CLB was populated?

Tags: c#, text, selecteditem, checkedlistbox

I have two CheckedListBoxes that look the same (except for the contents). I load one like so:

```
private void PopulateReportsListBox()
{         
    checkedListBoxReports.Items.AddRange(
        ReportSchedulerConstsAndUtils.Reports.ToArray<object>());
}

public static List<string> Reports = new List<string>
{ 
        "Produce Usage", 
        "Delivery Performance",
        "Fill Rate by Customer / Location",
        "Price Compliance"
};
```

With that one, I can get the value displayed in the CLB's ItemCheck event like so:

```
private void checkedListBoxReports_ItemCheck(object sender, 
    ItemCheckEventArgs iceargs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxReports.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (i != iceargs.Index) checkedListBoxReports.SetItemChecked(i, 
false);
    }
    String selectedRpt = checkedListBoxReports.SelectedItem.ToString();
    DisableParameterGroupBoxes();
    EnableParameterGroupBox(selectedRpt);
}
```

"selectedRpt" holds the value I expect ("Produce Usage" if the first item is selected, etc.).

However, I load the other CLB like this, from a DB:

```
private void PopulateUnitsListBox()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new 
        SqlConnection(ReportSchedulerConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new 
            SqlCommand(ReportSchedulerConstsAndUtils.SelectUnitsQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DataSource = dt;
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DisplayMember = "Unit";
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).ValueMember = "Unit";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...and I cannot access the display value in its ItemCheck event. I have to use the CLB's Text proprty rather than SelectedItem.ToString(). If I use the latter, I get (for all items), "System.Data.DataRowView"

Why? And are there any "gotchas" I should be aware of when using "Text"? Is it reliable/do I need to Trim() it?

Comment: In the second case you bound the control, so each Item (including `SelectedItem`) is one row of the datatable.  When they are bound I usually use `SelectedValueChanged` event and examine the `SelectedValue` becaue that is where the piece of info I want is mapped to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedItem` property returns the currently selected object in the collection that are using as a source, not the text displayed in the control.

When `CheckedListBox` will display the items, control first checks for property `DisplayMember`, if the specified property does not exist on the object or the value of `DisplayMember` is an empty string, the results of the object's `ToString()` method are displayed instead.

In your first `CheckedListBox` you are using an array of objects as item collection, where elements are actually strings and `DisplayMember` property is empty. Therefore the item and displayed text are the same, the string.

In your second `CheckedListBox` you are using a `DataTable` (which you can see it as an enumerable of `DataRowView`) as item collection, using `DisplayMember` = "Unit". Therefore, in this case `SelectedItem` is a `DataRowView` and text displayed is the member "Unit".

If you want to work always with text displayed in both CheckedListBoxes, then use the property you said `Text`. This property gets the text displayed of the currently selected item (no matter the source).

```
private void checkedListBoxReports_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs iceargs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxReports.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (i != iceargs.Index) 
            checkedListBoxReports.SetItemChecked(i, false);
    }

    string selectedRpt = checkedListBoxReports.Text;

    DisableParameterGroupBoxes();
    EnableParameterGroupBox(selectedRpt);
}
```

About your concerns for this property:

`Text` will return exactly the value of the function `ToString()` or the value of property specified in `DisplayMember`.

Also, you can searches for a item setting this property, the item whose displayed text is equal to the specified text will be selected.

If the `SelectionMode` property is set to `SelectionMode.MultiExtended`, this property returns the text of the first selected item.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do CheckedListBox's SelectedItem work differently depending on how the CLB was populated?

It doesn't work differently. It always returns an object from [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) collection or null. It's a shortcut to something like this

```
int selectedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;
object selectedItem = selectedIndex >= 0 ? listBox.Items[selectedIndex] : null;
```

> "selectedRpt" holds the value I expect ("Produce Usage" if the first item is selected, etc.).

and then

> I have to use the CLB's Text property rather than SelectedItem.ToString(). If I use the latter, I get (for all items), "System.Data.DataRowView"

You shouldn't be using `SelectedItem` (or any `Items` collection item) `.ToString()` method for getting the display text at the first place.

The control itself uses some logic to determine that text - and yes, in some case in could be `ToString()` method, but not always - for instance `DisplayMember` property changes that behavior.

But the point is that you don't need to know that logic. The control exposes publicly the method it's using internally. It's called (surprisingly) [GetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public string GetItemText(
    object item
)
```

and according to the documentation

> Returns the text representation of the specified item.

and also

> If the **DisplayMember** property is not specified, the value returned by GetItemText is the value of the item's **ToString** method. Otherwise, the method returns the string value of the member specified in the **DisplayMember** property for the object specified in the item parameter.

Shortly, you should always use that method.

- for selected item:

  `listBox.GetItemText(listBox.SelectedItem)`
- for specific index:

  `listBox.GetItemText(listBox.Items[index])`